# Magento Shopping Cart: One Item is not showing

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, product, invisible

I have a problem with the shopping cart in one of my shops.

When I add a product to my cart it's visible and all. Everything working fine.
But when I add the Product with ID 33 to the cart it is just not showing. The price gets higher and gets displayed but not the product. Every product else gets displayed.

I tried to clean the cache, reindex and nothing worked.

Comment: So, you are not seeing the item picture?

Comment: @BetoCastillo I only see the amount of Products in the cart. Nothing else.

Comment: Do you mean the top cart? or the checkout/cart page?

Comment: @BetoCastillo I mean the checkout/cart page: http://de.tinypic.com/r/who6iu/8

Comment: Do you have some public url to debug the site?

Comment: @BetoCastillo I sent the URL via the contact form on your website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error... was me!

I had this in the styles.css:

`.data-table tr.first{
    display:none;

}`

That means it was not displayed cause of the CSS...
the code was for the product-view so I just added .product-view:

`.product-view .data-table tr.first{
    display:none;

}`

Problem solved.
Thanks to all who tried to help me.
Sorry for wasting your time

_
Marco